# CQEngine query overhead / precompiled parameterized queries

Tags: cqengine

When I query an indexed collection many times and the query is the same and only differs in the attribute value, how big is the overhead to execute it?

Is there a way to precompile a parameterized query to get rid of this overhead?

Edit: Here's a simple benchmark showing that making multiple retrievals from a CQEngine collection with a hash index tends to be ~18 times slower than retrieving items from a LinkedHashMap.

https://github.com/Inego/cqe-simple-benchmark/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/Benchmark.kt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for parameterized queries per-se.

However if you would like to reduce the overhead of constructing queries frequently, such as the impact on garbage collection, you can leverage the fact that queries are immutable and stateless, and cache frequently used queries.

Queries are trees. So you can also cache frequently used branches of queries and reassemble query trees on the fly where branches are retrieved from cache.

However that said, generally the overhead of constructing queries should be pretty small. Id recommend to benchmark your application to see if this really is worthwhile.

Comment: I've edited my question to add a link to a simple benchmark showing that multiple "equals" retrievals from a Hash index are about 18 times slower than "retrieving" from a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Those will never be equal in performance. Does it have a measurable impact on your application's latency? That is 18 times slower than something measured in nanoseconds right? A hash lookup will generally be faster than a lookup to a hash index via CQEngine. Partly because CQEngine is a layer on top of potentially lots of different data structures and will try to compute a query plan to access the data structures (this consumes some CPU cycles). And partly because as you found, constructing query trees does have some overhead.

Comment: True! We use CQEngine for the purpose of being able to make arbitrary queries. But we also have this edge case when we use the same indexed collection to quickly find items by a unique field, where the "query plan" is in fact the same, which is "to lookup the hash map backing the collection". What do you think about the possibility to have an API to obtain / cache / reuse CQEngine query plans?